# What does the underscore mean in literal numbers?

Tags: ruby

What does that mean?
`0.0..10_000.0`

Comment: What you have there is a `Range` from `0.0` to `10000.0`.

Comment: Also same as (0.0)..(10_000.0) in this case range "0 to 10_000"

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Underscores are ignored.  You can put them in to make them more readable.

Comment: But only if it's one underscore, two of them raise and error. Not sure if it was always like that or just the recent versions. :)

Answer (score 14):

It’s just a syntax convenience to separate the thousands:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts 1_000 + 1_000_000'  #=> 1001000
```

Comment: This is a Ruby question, so how about a Ruby example?

Comment: I don’t know Ruby, but I thought this was a safe bet given Ruby’s inspiration with Perl. You’re welcome to edit the answer.

Answer (score 9):

It is a Range object, of the kind a..b

In this case it gives you the numbers from 0 to 10,000 as Floats.

the underscore '_' is ignored, and used for readability, so 10_000 is equivalent 10,000.

Buy adding .0 to each part of the range, the numbers would be considered as floats instead of integers, so you won't be able to iterate over the range (the each method would raise an exception).